# Laravel Ajax panel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My problem is when I bring up mouse on 2nd page button the link it shows in monitor down left corner is this: `home/?page=2` but I need that it would show this: `ajax/comments/?page=2`. However it shows `ajax/comments/?page=2` **WHEN** I press button to go to the 2nd page and after that it starts to work.

```
    <div class="row content col-md-9">
    <div class="panel panel-default widget">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                Recent Comments</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-group">
            @foreach($comments as $comment)
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                            <img src="{{$comment->author->image}}"  alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-11">
                            <div>
                                <a href="{{$comment->article->slug}}">
                                    {{$comment->article->title}}</a>
                                <div class="mic-info">
                                    By: <a href="#">{{$comment->author->name}}</a> {{$comment->created_at}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-text">
                                {{$comment->body}}
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            @endforeach

            </ul>
            <div class="text-center">{!! $comments->render() !!}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<script>
        $(window).on('hashchange',function(){
            page = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
            getProducts(page);
        });
        $(document).on('click','.pagination a', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
            // getProducts(page);
            location.hash = page;
        });
        function getProducts(page){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax/comments?page=' + page
            }).done(function(data){
                $('.content').html(data);
            });
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I just made this change:

```
{!! str_replace('/home/?', '/ajax/comments?',$comments->render()) !!}
```

and now its working